# Ivy not pulling transitive dependencies on jars with classifiers

Tags: jar, ant, settings, ivy

We are moving from Ant w/ Ivy to Maven. As part of this move, we have taken projects with multiple jars that use to be separate Ivy artifacts into Maven artifacts with classifiers.

The new Maven projects have no problems with this. However, our Ivy projects can't locate the `pom.xml` for the classifier.

In our Maven repository, their is a single `pom.xml` for all of the jars in the project:

```
http://repo.vegicorp.com/l/com/vegicorp/foo/1.0.0/foo-1.0.0.pom
http://repo.vegicorp.com/l/com/vegicorp/foo/1.0.0/foo-1.0.0.jar
http://repo.vegicorp.com/l/com/vegicorp/foo/1.0.0/foo-1.0.0-client.jar
http://repo.vegicorp.com/l/com/vegicorp/foo/1.0.0/foo-1.0.0-test.jar
```

Looking at the output of an debug Ant build, I see that it's looking in our Maven repository at:

```
http://repo.vegicorp.com/com/vegicorp/foo/1.0.0/foo-1.0.0-client.pom
```

It's appending the *classifier* to the name of the `pom.xml` file! It can find and download the jar, but without the `pom.xml`, it can't figure out the dependencies. Our build fails because the dependencies aren't downloaded.

I assume there's some setting in `ivysettings.xml` that will let Ivy know that Pom files don't have the classifier appended to them, but I haven't figured it out.

So, how do I fix this issue? I *might* be able to copy the missing `pom.xml` into our Repository (This is Artifactory), but I am not sure if I can. (Maybe there's a setting in Artifactory that can help resolve this?).

Answer (score 0):

You need to say to ivy to use [lBiblio resolver](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/resolver/ibiblio.html). You can disable looking for poms, quote from lBilbio link:

> When using the m2compatible flag, you can disable the use of poms by
>   setting the usepoms flag to false

If that one doesn't work, more refined settings can be achieved with [packager resolver](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/resolver/packager.html) - at the bottom of the page there is a not on classifier attribute.

In addition (for any resolver), you may need to set up artifact pattern properly to actually find the artifacts.

Comment: I'm using the IBibilo resolver. I don't want to disable the use of poms because I need them to find the dependencies of the jars I am downloading. I'll try setting up the packager resolver.

Comment: I'm having problems with the packager resolver. I can either get it to see the classifier or not see the classifier, so I have a choice of finding the POM or the JAR. Grr.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a *work around*, or maybe this is the way I should have been doing it the whole time.

I was defining the dependencies in my `ivy.xml` files this way:

```
<dependency org="com.vegicorp" name="foo" version="1.0"
    conf="compile->default"/>
```

Everything is under the `<dependency>` entity and no sub-entities and it worked just fine. By default, it found the `pom.xml`, converted it into an `ivy.xml` dependency file, and downloaded the jar too.

When we started adding the classifier, we did it this way:

```
<dependency org="com.vegicorp" name="foo" version="1.0"
    conf="compile->default" maven:classifier="client"/>
```

Again, putting everything inside the `<dependency>` entity with no sub-entities. Ivy then looks for the jar at `com/vegicorp/foo/1.0.0/foo-1.0.0-client.jar` which is correct, but can't locate the POM at `com/vegicorp/foo/1.0.0/foo-1.0.0-client.com`. We never noticed this before because we only had two or three third party jars that had classifiers, and none of these jars had dependencies on other jars. It didn't matter that the jar downloaded without the associated POM.

Everything broke when we started defining our own jars with classifiers because our jars had other jar dependencies.

However, if I used the `<artifact>` entity and put the classifier in that, everything worked:

```
<dependency org="com.vegicorp" name="foo" version="1.0" 
    conf="compile->default">
    <artifact name="foo" ext="jar" maven:classifier="client"/>
</dependency>
```

Ivy finds the correct location in the repository at `com/vegicorp/foo/1.0.0`, and then downloads the POM without the classifier at `com/vegicorp/foo/1.0.0/foo-1.0.0.pom`. It then locates the artifact at this location with the classifer at `com/vegicorp/foo/1.0.0/foo-1.0.0-client.jar`